# Counting matrices with specific condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of 3x3 0,1 matrices and I want to count how many of them have 0 on diagonal and pseudo-antisymmetric, i.e `A[i][j] != A[j][i]` (if `A[i][j] = 1` then `A[j][i]` should be 0).

How can I implement this? I was trying similar approach as for counting symmetric matrices(here [Counting symmetric matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64899526/counting-symmetric-matrices)), but it doesn't work here.

Comment: are you using numpy?

Comment: Nope, condition are similar to one's using in the post I linked, but numpy is acceptable

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `a` is a 3x3 numpy array,

```
(a + np.eye(len(a)) == 1 - a.T).all()
```

Explanation:

- `a.T` flips the matrix.
- `1 - a.T` inverts flipped matrix
- in the inverted matrix, diagonal elements are expected to be 1. Fix: add a diagonal matrix, `a + np.eye(len(a))`
- test passes only if all elements satisfy the condition: `(... == ...).all()`

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

You could use your existing `is_symmetric` function and create a new is `has_zero_main_diagonal` one:

```
def pretty_print(matrix):
    for row in matrix:
        print(*row)

def has_zero_main_diagonal(matrix, n):
    return all(matrix[i][i] == 0 for i in range(n))

def is_symmetric(matrix, n):
    return all(matrix[i][j] == matrix[j][i] for i in range(n) for j in range(n))
```

**Informal Testing:**

```
symmetric_zero_diag = [[0, 1, 1],
                       [1, 0, 1],
                       [1, 1, 0]]

symmetric_non_zero_diag = [[0, 1, 1],
                           [1, 0, 1],
                           [1, 1, 1]]

asymmetric_zero_diag = [[0, 1, 1],
                        [1, 0, 1],
                        [0, 1, 0]]

asymmetric_non_zero_diag = [[1, 1, 1],
                            [1, 1, 1],
                            [0, 1, 1]]

testcases = {
    'symmetric_zero_diag': symmetric_zero_diag,
    'symmetric_non_zero_diag': symmetric_non_zero_diag,
    'asymmetric_zero_diag': asymmetric_zero_diag,
    'asymmetric_non_zero_diag': asymmetric_non_zero_diag
}

num_pseudo_antisymmetric_zero_diag = 0
for testcase_name, matrix in testcases.items():
    print(f'{testcase_name}:')
    pretty_print(matrix)
    print(f'has_zero_main_diagonal={has_zero_main_diagonal(matrix, 3)}')
    print(f'is_symmetric={is_symmetric(matrix, 3)}')
    is_pseudo_antisymmetric_zero_diag = has_zero_main_diagonal(matrix, 3) and not is_symmetric(matrix, 3)
    if is_pseudo_antisymmetric_zero_diag:
        num_pseudo_antisymmetric_zero_diag += 1
    print((f'has_zero_main_diagonal and not is_symmetric='
           f'{is_pseudo_antisymmetric_zero_diag}'))
    print()

print(f'Number of matrices that are pseudo-antisymmetric with a zero_diag: {num_pseudo_antisymmetric_zero_diag}')
```

**Output:**

```
symmetric_zero_diag:
0 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 0
has_zero_main_diagonal=True
is_symmetric=True
has_zero_main_diagonal and not is_symmetric=False

symmetric_non_zero_diag:
0 1 1
1 0 1
1 1 1
has_zero_main_diagonal=False
is_symmetric=True
has_zero_main_diagonal and not is_symmetric=False

asymmetric_zero_diag:
0 1 1
1 0 1
0 1 0
has_zero_main_diagonal=True
is_symmetric=False
has_zero_main_diagonal and not is_symmetric=True

asymmetric_non_zero_diag:
1 1 1
1 1 1
0 1 1
has_zero_main_diagonal=False
is_symmetric=False
has_zero_main_diagonal and not is_symmetric=False

Number of matrices that are pseudo-antisymmetric with a zero_diag: 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much !